# Macbook air 2012, installed new battery, bottom of trackpad sounds loose/clicky now, ideas?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, trackpad, repair, hardware

My other one couldn't hold a charge well but didn't look bloated at all to have warped anything in my system.

All that was weird that happened was that I lost one of the bottom case screws (small ones), could this cause it? (I could get replacement from amazon).

I'm going to go back in and tighten all the case screws, battery screws and tighten the trackpad screws, that's about all I can do right?

Comment: You disassembled the MacBook Air 2012 and you ended up with an extra screw?  Yes, you did something wrong.  Also be extremely careful, some screws are longer than others and need to be put back exactly where they belong.  There are guides at ifixit dot com that include step by step instructions and photos. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for reply, no, I lost a screw, so the bottom case is missing one, ordered replacements.